# url query string change by jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, parameters, get

I am in a page http://www.sample.com/index.php

How can add URL query string.For ex when i click a button URL became http://www.sample.com/index.php?value=10 without page reload.by using jquery ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for History API, check out this [`history.js`](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) library,
https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

**Demo:** http://browserstate.github.com/history.js/demo/

Answer (score 0):

New HTML 5 browsers support the History API ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history), [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html)):

```
window.history.pushState(stateObj, title, url);
```

In a pre HTML 5 browser you can set the hash tag ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange), [W3C example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp))

```
window.location.hash = "state";
```

Older browsers that do not support changing of the hash tag cannot use this feature.